# В sql запросе к бд firebird- получаю ошибку "Column unknown",хотя он есть

Tags: sql, firebird

Всем привет! я делаю запрос на Laravel к бд firebird и у меня выходит следующая ошибка:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: -206 Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -206 Column unknown ГАВС At line 1, column 35. (SQL: SELECT * FROM PULKOVO_VIEW where GENAGENT_NAME="ГАВС")
```

Мой запрос
$reestr= DB::select('SELECT * FROM PULKOVO_VIEW  where GENAGENT_NAME="ГАВС"');

[image: Скрин таблицы]

Буду рад любой помощи!

Comment: Ну надо же хоть иногда читать документацию! Вот и почитайте, какие кавычки используются для экранирования имён объектов и какие для литералов. https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/Firebird_Language_Reference_RUS.pdf стр. 21-22.

Comment: @Akina Спасибо за помощь, но ваш совет не помог. Я не нашел нужной информации

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Руководство по языку SQL СУБД Firebird 2.5: Firebird 2.5.9](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/Firebird_Language_Reference_RUS.pdf)

"Идентификаторы". Страница 22.

> Имя с разделителями заключается в **двойные кавычки**.

"Строковые литералы". Страница 38.

> Строковые литералы могут содержать произвольные символы, допустимые для применяемого набора символов. Весь литерал заключается в **апострофы**.